# How to use hg to back branch?

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I have local branch and master branch. I use hg merge local branch with master branch, after that I find that master branch version is modified and I have to merge with new master branch.

I don't know how to back local branch status and merge new master branch.

Answer (score 1):

If you committed the merge and *then* found that there were new changesets on master, you could do either of:

1. `hg pull` the new changesets, then `hg merge` again, then push the two merges.
2. `hg strip` your merge, then `hg pull` and `hg merge <localbranch>` again.

If you haven't committed first merge yet, you could `hg update default -C` to throw out the merge changes, then `hg pull` and `hg merge <localbranch>` again.